# Restart script as admin, avoiding the error message

Tags: autohotkey

The code in the example picked from the AHK Docs. If the script is launched with non-admin permissions, it would automatically restart itself as admin (or show you a UAC prompt).

However, if you click "No" in UAC prompt, AHK will show a window with error message. Is there a way to avoid this error message?

```
If Not A_IsAdmin
{
    Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    ExitApp
}

MsgBox Hello World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> If Target cannot be launched, an error window is displayed and the current thread is exited, unless the string UseErrorLevel is included in the third parameter or the error is caught by a Try/Catch statement.
>
> UseErrorLevel: UseErrorLevel can be specified alone or in addition to one of the above words (by separating it from the other word with a space). If the launch fails, this option skips the warning dialog, sets ErrorLevel to the word ERROR, and allows the current thread to continue.

So set the third parameter to `UseErrorLevel`, to skip the error window.